# Django Rest Framework - CreateAPIView doesn't let use POST method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to create a view, that will accept POST requests and create new instances of my model(see bottom of post). I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfIB-LthIpE&index=9&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTOcOVdZF-th7BS_GYGguAS) tutorial. The problem is that when I access URL associated with view, which inherits from CreateAPIView I dont see a form in html representation of API for creation of new instances and I also see that it accepts GET requests, not POST as it mentioned in documentation.

Page looks like this

[image]

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, CreateAPIView
from datingapp.models import Profile
from .serializers import ProfileSerializer, ProfileCreateSerializer

class ProfilesAPIView(ListAPIView):
  queryset = Profile.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

class ProfileCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
  queryset = Profile.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ProfileCreateSerializer
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from datingapp.views import ProfilesAPIView, ProfileCreateAPIView

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'api/profiles/', ProfilesAPIView.as_view(), name='list'),
   url(r'api/profiles/create/$', ProfileCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='create')
   ]
```

My serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from datingapp.models import Profile

class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = [
        'name',
        'age',
        'heigth'
        'location',
    ]

class ProfileCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = [
        'name',
        'age',
        'heigth'
        'location',
    ]
```

In my settings.py I have crispy_forms installed.

What am I doing wrong ?

UPD: here is what I want to achieve

[image]

As you see there is a form and it accepts only POST and also says that GET is not allowed

Comment: Are you wondering why `CreateApiView` doesn't accept `GET`? What response would you expect? If you want to use multiple methods on the same route, you can use ModelViewSets.

Comment: I want to achieve the same as on screenshot at the bottom

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood. Your question makes sense now.  The response does not look like I would expect for a `CreateAPIView`. It looks like a `ListAPIView`

Comment: Likely due to your permission settings. In my django settings `REST_FRAMEWORK = {...'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES: ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny']'}` This is best practice of course, and should always have some sort of authentication.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is in your router. The first pattern matches both `api/profiles/` and `api/profiles/create/` so the second one will never be evaluated. You are seeing the ProfilesAPIView instead of the create view.

```
 url(r'api/profiles/', ProfilesAPIView.as_view(), name='list'),
 url(r'api/profiles/create/$', ProfileCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='create')
```

To fix it, either swap the order of the urls, or add a `$` to the end of the first pattern. `r'api/profiles/$'`

Answer (score 5):

I was following a tutorial and had a similar problem. Probably I was not following the same version of Django Rest Framework and they had changes.
But I solved this problem doing this.

```
class AssetBundleList(generics.ListAPIView):
```

to

```
class AssetBundleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
```

Hope this helps someone.